# How can i fix spam filtering with recaptcha integration?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, spam, hardcode

Two devs who previously worked at the company I now worked for implemented ReCaptcha into a hard coded site. They did not document how they did this for the company. The implementation does not seem to be working as hundreds of spam submissions are being sent through the site daily successfully. I need to be able to fix this and implement this solution so that the client is no longer receiving these spam submissions.

I downloaded the files to the site and opened them in VS. Code. I found an "anchor.html" file that seems to host the information for ReCaptcha that had been implemented as well as an "api.js.download" file. There is also a "recaptcha_en.js.doanload" file. I'm not sure how to fix this or even where to begin.

Comment: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-web-pages#html-button) describes how to add reCAPTCHA to forms, so you can guard against spam submissions.